# Why won't swift allow nested if statements along with others?

Tags: swift, if-statement, nested

So for the past hour or so, I've been trying to nest three if statements in swift but nothing is working. I'm literally pulling my hair out for something that seems so simple and yet I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
var population = 125442
var message: String
var hasAPostOffice: Bool = true

if population < 10000 {
    message = "\(population) is a pretty small town"
}else if population >= 10000 && population < 50000 {
        message = "\(population) is a medium sized town"
}else{
        message = "\(population) is a very large town!"
}else = {
    population >= 200000 && population < 120000 {
        message = "\(population) is a super huge town"
}
}
print(message)

if !hasAPostOffice {
    print("Where could I buy stamps?")
}
```

Comment: This part of your code has some problem from first look else{
        message = "\(population) is a very large town!"
}else = {
    population >= 200000 && population < 120000 {
        message = "\(population) is a super huge town"
}

Comment: What do you want to achieve with else = after else statement?

Comment: FYI - there are only two `if` statements in your attempt to use three.

Comment: What about `50,001` to `119,000`? That'll fall through to the default case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested should look like -

```
if population < 10000 {
    message = "\(population) is a pretty small town"
}else if population >= 10000 && population < 50000 {
    message = "\(population) is a medium sized town"
}else if(// some condition here){
    message = "\(population) is a very large town!"
}else {

}
```

Plus what is this condition

```
population >= 200000 && population < 120000 {
```

In my opinion this can never be true as population cannot be both less than 120000 and more than 200000 at the same time.

So check your logic here

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for pointing out. Missed it in the copy past. My bad. Have corrected it

Comment: Great, Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is not restricted to Swift. Every else statement must correlate to only one if statement.

In your code, you have two else statements. One else statements looks like it should be an else if since there's an attempted condition that you try to get evaluated. Therefore, create an else if statement out of it if you have a condition that depends on an expression.

```
if population < 10000 {
  message = "\(population) is a pretty small town"
}
else if population >= 10000 && population < 50000 {
  message = "\(population) is a medium sized town"
}
else if population >= 200000 && population < 120000{
 message = "\(population) is a super huge town"
}
else{
    message = "\(population) is a very large town!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is off; The solution is to add the final else as the largest value:

```
if population < 10000 {
    message = "\(population) is a pretty small town"
} else if population >= 10000 && population < 50000 {
    message = "\(population) is a medium sized town"
} else if population >= 50000 && population < 120000 {
    message = "\(population) is a very large town"
} else if population >= 120000 && population < 200000 {
    message = "\(population) is a super huge town"
} else {
    message = "\(population) is enormous!"
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's just my bad code early in the morning. I've fixed it on my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works more nicely with a switch statement:

```
let population = 125442
let hasAPostOffice = true

let message: String
switch population {
    case 0 ..< 10_000: message = "\(population) is a pretty small town"
    case 10_000 ..< 50_000: message = "\(population) is a medium sized town"
    case 120_001 ... 200_000: message = "\(population) is a super huge town"
    default: message = "\(population) is a very large town!"
}

print(message)

if !hasAPostOffice {
    print("Where could I buy stamps?")
}
```